# How to pass parameter in Rails routes but protect it from user setting it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

It's easy to pass a parameter to a controller, as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533960/rails-3-routing-passing-params-from-routes-rb):

```
root :to => "pages#show", :id => 3
```

My question is how can the controller ensure this is set programmatically, ie guard against a user manually setting the parameter? Or is there any other mechanism which would let a matching route pass data across to the controller.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to prevent a user from manually editing the URL. The few ways around it the id being editable that I have used when the situation warrants it:

1. Use Ajax requests to load the item so the id is hidden from the user
2. Use something like [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) for your model so the id is a slug which is tough to spoof
3. Do something to obfuscate the URL like the example I put in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587409/prevent-cheating-in-rails-html5-game-app-rails-3-2-html5-javascript/29200394#29200394). The gist of it, is you add a new field called `url_code` and auto-generate one per row in your model and use that as your `#id` for your route. (Keeping examples below the same model as other example for sake of time, see context over there).

#### model

```
Page < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :url_code, :uniqueness => true
  after_initialize :create_url_code

  def create_url_code
self.url_code=SecureRandom.hex(4) if self.url_code.nil?
  end
end
```

### in controller:

```
  @page = Page.find_by_url_code(params[:id])
```

Comment: Thanks for the workarounds, but tbh I'd rather just make a new route instead of relying on being unguessable/obfuscated.

Comment: well, using #1 (ajax) can satisfy your concern that a user didn't enter it (because you can restrict to JSON requests) but if you do standard routes you can't change because it's default browser request behavior (in url bar)